# SVG disappears if filter is applied

Tags: html, css, svg

I've been playing around with `SVG`s in websites, and I've been trying to get `filter`s to work, but I can't seem to get it right.

The problem is that the `svg` disappears completely once I apply a defined `filter`. I've tried to apply the `filter` inline, just to see if it worked, like this:

```
<symbol id="circle" viewBox="0 0 400 209.603" filter="url('#blur-filter')">
...
</symbol>
```

but with no success.

Ultimately, my goal is that I would be able to apply the `filter`s via CSS, but I can't seem to get it to work, and this is the first time I've really played around with `SVG`s, so I don't know if I'm making some obvious mistake.

#### Code:

```css
.svg-circle:hover {
  filter: url("#blur-filter");
}
.svg-grey {
  fill: #333;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display:none">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur-filter">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2" />
    </filter>
    <symbol id="circle" viewBox="0 0 400 209.603">
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#circle" class="svg-circle svg-grey"/>
</svg>
```

I want the `filter` to be applied when I hover over the element. My other question is how I can incorporate this with CSS `transitions`, so that the `blur` gets applied gradually, like other css3 `transitions`.

I also want the filters to be global, so they can be reused across multiple `svg` images whenever I want, so define once, and reuse.

I've also created a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/naxez7/pen/LGaoZE) to demonstrate my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove your `style="display:none"` and add `width:0` to your first `svg`

```css
.svg-circle:hover {
  filter: url("#blur-filter");
}
.svg-grey {
  fill: #333;
}
svg:first-of-type {
  width:0
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur-filter">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2" />
    </filter>
    <symbol id="circle" viewBox="0 0 400 209.603">
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#circle" class="svg-circle svg-grey"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: This seems like a good train of thought, but the `display: none`is there for a reason. As you can see on your example, the svg tag takes up some space, which is not what I want. I want definitions at the top of my html, and they should take up no space. Do you have any idea on how to get around this?

Comment: @Pavlin, but they do not take space by default.

Comment: @Qwertiy but it does take up space, if you look at his first snippet.

Comment: @Pavlin I updated my first snippet, to remove the space, take a look

Comment: @Pavlin, because you aren't specifiing the sizes. See my answer.

Comment: You still have the space between svg tags. Classic problem with inline-blocks.

Comment: Yes, I can fix the existing spacing easily now. This seems to be a very strange "feature" of svgs... I've got it to work now.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `display: none;` on the definitions SVG and give it 0 dimensions. This should do it. Somehow the filter may be inheriting that `display: none`.

```css
.svg-circle:hover {
  filter: url("#blur-filter");
}
.svg-grey {
  fill: #333;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur-filter">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2" />
    </filter>
    <symbol id="circle" viewBox="0 0 400 209.603">
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#circle" class="svg-circle svg-grey"/>
</svg>
```

As for the transition, I don't think you can do that by using referenced filters.

Comment: As I remember, you can, if they both are inlined into same html and ids are unique or if you specify the path (not just an anchor) to other svg.

Comment: Your example does work, but it does the opposite of what I want to achieve. I want svg definitions at the top, so that I can reuse them multiple times across the page. If I did it the way you've done it, I'd need to copy the paths several times throughout the page.

Comment: @Pavlin I was wrong with my first assumption. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.svg-circle:hover {
  filter: url("#blur-filter");
}

.svg-grey {
  fill: #333;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur-filter">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2" />
    </filter>
    <symbol id="circle" viewBox="0 0 400 209.603">
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg><svg width="400" height="210">
  <use xlink:href="#circle" class="svg-circle svg-grey"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: A snippet without explanations? that's usually not a good answer

Comment: @dippas, see the [comment](/questions/35436801/svg-disappears-if-filter-is-applied/35437554#comment58573184_35437341).